# Avocado leaves are browning and shriveling up

Tags: avocado, urban-gardening

The plant was fine until a few days ago when i finally brought it outside. It has spent all of winter indoors in the same pot.

The browning on this one greatly differs from the one that has salt burns, this one is a much more mild, greenish brown, spread evenly throughout the leaf.

Also note that the only leaves affected thus far are the ones facing the sunny side. 
[image]
One more leaf is just starting to brown, but hasn't started to shrivel up yet.

Comment: Looks like sunburn. You have to slowly adapt the plant to sunlight

Comment: It's currently on the south-facing balcony where it's sunny most of the day. The north facing one gets less sun. Would this help?

Comment: The best is to give the plant a few hours sun per day to start with. When you have a bit of sunlight per day, then the north window is perfect. You can move the plant to south again after a week or so (best on a cloudy day)

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the advice!